# C# Json Complex object deserializing using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "students":
   [{
     "firstName":"first",
     "middleName":"middle",
     "lastName":"last",
     "studentId":"123-123-123",
     "joiningBatch":{"semesterName":"Fall2017"},
     "semesters":[],
     "courses":[],
     "department":1,
     "degree":1
    }]
}
```

I have created a student class and have set all the properties, names and id have a fixed format which i enforced using regex. Joining batch holds another custom class Semester which only has one variable in it. Department and Degree are both enums,
I wrote the data to a json file , but when I try to deserialize it and put in a List, I get errors, My regex checks fail. I can see that the data is in the class, but it somehow fails be deserialize, I am completely lost since I am a total beginner in C#. Searched a lot but none of the solutions work for me.

```
public string jsonData = File.ReadAllText("data.json");    
public List<Student> studentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(jsonData)
              ?? new List<Student>();
```

This is the code I wrote to get data from the file and deserialize it. Any clue would be welcome as to what I am doing wrong here.

P.S. Department and Degree, int values are being read correctly, so I think the data is being read, but the string values are causing the problems, I might be wrong. My intention is to read the json data from the file, deserialize it, generate a list of Student objects since I serialized a list of Student objects and wrote  them to a file.

Update: I changed my json to following format

```
[{"_firstName":"q","_middleName":"q","_lastName":"q","_studentId":"123-123-123","_joiningBatch":{"_semesterName":"Fall2017"},"_semesters":[],"_courses":[],"_department":1,"_degree":1}]
```

Once again it does not work, I tried the solution mentioned in the question that was marked as a duplicate of this question, but that also failed.

Comment: Your json looks like an object with a students property, but your deserialization code deserializez a list. You should deserialize the same object type, or an object with a student property on type List<Student>

Comment: No one searches SO anymore before asking a json question. Almost every answer has a link to http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: My json is a list of students, I just took a sample of when there is only one student in the list.

Comment: No it isn't You actually trying to deserialize a JSON object, not array. That's why it does not works. You should either pass an array (everything in [] including brackets) or to deserialize it as class with property of List<Student> students.

Comment: eshan: Read what Titian said again. He is correct.